# USB to serial adapter randomly kills Bluetooth after some time

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, thinkpad, serial-port

I'm on a ThinkPad T14 AMD Gen1 with Ubuntu 22.04.2.

I have an USB to serial adapter connected to my computer that shows up as`/dev/ttyUSB0`. I use it to receive/send data from/to a Raspberry Pi. This works well until at some point, the serial connection seems to crash, which I recognize, because at that point my Bluetooth mouse ceases to work.

This randomly happens after some minutes, sometimes an hour. Maybe because the adapter has a hiccup with the received data or whatever (I can't reproduce the issue, it just happens after some time).

The problem is that this makes the whole serial and Bluetooth device unavailable. I can't turn on Bluetooth again, because it doesn't exist anymore. The same for `/dev/ttyUSB0`, it just doesn't exist anymore. Unplugging and plugging in again doesn't fix it.

The only solution I found so far is a reboot, but that is a lot of work to do for something that happens that often.

So my question is: is there any way to revive the serial controller or whatever else breaks here without the need for a reboot? I tried `$ lspci` which reliably revives missing SD card readers, but it doesn't work for serial and BT.

Comment: In terminal run `sudo dmesg -w` and see if it has any clues when the problem occurs

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try.